# how to use an array as Global and access it from all other files in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have a file called users.php where I am adding usernames in array as below

```
<?php

 $users = array("alexritz","katrob","diaman","janber","denivar","hamrop","calvik");

?>
```

everytime I need this array in another php file I use `require 'users.php';` and do whatever I need with this array.

I want to make my array global and use it across all files without using `require`. I know how to use session and it works for me but I am chasing the global how to make it work. I tried as below

> users.php

```
<?php

 $users = array("alexritz","katrob","diaman","janber","denivar","hamrop","calvik");

function globalUsers() {
return $GLOBALS['users']; }

globalUsers();

?>
```

then in any other php file I just call `globalUsers();` but it's not working.

Any ideas please ? Thank you.

Comment: "_but it's not working._" means what exactly? Your function `return`s something, just calling it won't do anything, you'd need to output the stuff it returns. Also, you'd still need to `require/include` that file somewhere for every other script to access `globalUsers()`.

Comment: something wrong is here... how did you use another file? just run it via console/web-server? somethig like 'https://localhost/register.php' and this file doesn't have 'require' ? it will not work in that way.. every time when you need a variables or functions you need to declare it directly or by require/include directives.

Comment: @Rahul I don't want to use sessions. I have it already working. I want to use Global variable

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated … Put `$GLOBALS['users'] = array(…);` into your include file, and then access via `$GLOBALS['users']` _anywhere_ after …?

Comment: @04FS  that's what i want to do but i get undefined index error when I access my array from another file

Comment: Well you will have to include the file that creates this array _somewhere_ …

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a globalized array, you might consider using `sessions``.

```
session_start();

// To save the array
$array = [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => 27,
];

$_SESSION['saved'] = $array;

// To get data from the array
$array = $_SESSION['saved'];
```

PS: Don't forget to use `session_start()` at the top of each file that will be using this.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is probably just returning your array in the function:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return array
 */
function globalUsers()
{
    return array("alexritz","katrob","diaman","janber","denivar","hamrop","calvik");
}
```

If you require that in the main file that requires everything else then the function should be available anywhere, no globals required! (thankfully)